is there way out from error "Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'"
I'm building an monolith spring project. I work with spring 3.4.0, java 17, jwt version 0.12.6.
I just design and set up entities and jwt infrastructures and I got this issue. Many times I looked for a wrong definition. I never figured out it.
that is full of error string
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [C:\Users\mrzcn\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce-backend\target\classes\com\example\ecommerce\security\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:\Users\mrzcn\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce-backend\target\classes\com\example\ecommerce\security\CustomUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EcommerceApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
and bellow files about error.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jwt.version>0.12.6</jwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


that is my User entity
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountStatus accountStatus;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart cart;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime registerDate;

    private LocalDateTime  deletedDate;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isMailVerified = false;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isPhoneNumberVerified = false;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isSmsAvailable = false;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isEmailAvailable = false;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isPushNotificationAvailable = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserActionLog> userActionLogs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Wishlist> wishlists;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Notification> notifications;

JwtAuthenticationFilter
package com.example.ecommerce.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtService jwtService, CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = getTokenFromHeader(request);

        if(token != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){

            String username = jwtService.extractUser(token);

            if(username != null && jwtService.isTokenValid(token)){
                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                setAuthentication(userDetails, request);
            }

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    private String getTokenFromHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return header.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setAuthentication(UserDetails userDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    }
}


CustomUserDetailsService:
package com.example.ecommerce.security;

import com.example.ecommerce.model.user.User;
import com.example.ecommerce.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }


}

if it neccessery there is CustomUserDetails:
package com.example.ecommerce.security;

import com.example.ecommerce.model.user.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRole().getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }
}


then finally UserRepository:
package com.example.ecommerce.repository;

import com.example.ecommerce.model.user.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);
}

Any idea ?
I have checked Entity relations and some different .properties configs. Is there any suggest to way out?

first check is your repository and main application have same base package. and try removing autowired from CustomUserDetailsService.
